# How to Retrieve Single MongoDB Embedded Document with Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to know how I can get an embedded document alone using Node and mongojs module. Here's some of my code for reference:

```
//Gets by ID
router.get('storm/:id',function(req,res,next){
    db.storms.findOne({_id:mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)},function(err,storm){
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(storm);
        }
    });
});
```

There I can get by the object ID, however, what I want to do is get an embedded object by a property other than ID.

Here is a collection for reference:

```
{
    "_id":"585761e497a4739e937fad8d",
    "user":"lloyd",
    "timestamp":"14:20",
    "storm":
    [
            {"message":"This is a test message number 7. I love making test messages.","stormtime":"14:21"},
            {"message":"This is a test message number 8. I love making test messages.","stormtime":"14:22"},
            {"message":"This is a test message number 9. I love making test messages.","stormtime":"14:23"}
    ]
}
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't work. I want to be able to access the property like I did above through the URL.

```
//Get messages in storm
router.get('storm/:stormtime',function(req,res,next){
    db.storms.find({"storm.stormtime":"14:23"},{"storm.$":1},function(err,storm){
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(storm);
        }
    });
});
```

What do you think I should do, especially in my query, to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.storms.find( { storm: { "$elemMatch": { "stormtime": "14:23" } } } );
```

This query should work for you. Just try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`find` and `findOne` always return whole documents, they don't return partial/embedded documents, but you can easily access them.

You started with good code, just need to add the accessor:

```
router.get('storm/:stormtime',function(req,res,next){
    db.storms.find({"storm.stormtime":"14:23"},{"storm.$":1},function(err, doc){
        if (err || !doc) return res.send(err || "no doc");
        res.json(doc.storm[0]); // This accesses the embedded object you want
    });
});
```